# Replace and Convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I made a script to import data from external file to a SQL Table (SQL 2012).
The first column of the external file was only number and the column of the SQL table is INT.

Now, in the external file, they have insert alpha numeric data like '6B32E' and it didn't synchronise correctly anymore.

I can't change the SQL column's type.

Is it possible to replace and convert as INT that kind of string. ?
My idea is to replace the alphabet letter by their place number in the alphabet.

In the example '6B32E' will becoming '62325'

Comment: What happens if you need to distinguish between the rows that were always 62325 and the rows converted to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `REPLACE` (26 times). It's not going to be pretty but it'll work. It will start something like this;

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (TextField nvarchar(5))
INSERT INTO #TestData (TextField)
VALUES
('6B32E')
,('A6E52')
,('58C69')
```

Query

```
SELECT
    TextField
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TextField,'A',1),'B',2),'C',3),'D',4),'E',5) IntField
FROM #TestData
```

Output

```
TextField   IntField
6B32E       62325
A6E52       16552
58C69       58369
```

Comment: You would have to use a lot more than 26 replaces though, what about non-alpha characters?

Comment: Yes, if there were non alpha characters then you'd need more replaces. I was addressing that OP asked how to replace alphabet characters with their corresponding position in the alphabet.